# How to calculate OOB error vs. features plot

Tags: r, python, feature-selection, random-forest

I have  dataset (numeric values from  30 th number raster brick and some classes for every pixel. (class value was taken from RF classification result)).
Well I know how to calculate  importance of features by sklearn or R, but no have idea how get this: I wish to plot how  OOB error grows with grow of numbers of features (number of raster in my stack).